# got TypeError when loading an exist model that saved by tf1.9 with tf1.8

Tags: python, tensorflow

> File "Predict.py", line 43, in **init**
>       self.Model = tf.keras.models.load_model( 'models_1/model_4' ) TypeError: **init**() got multiple values for keyword argument
>   'data_format'

the model_4 is saved from google colab. in which tensorflow version is 1.9. and the version of the tensorflow i use in local to load it is 1.8.